# What is the function and utility of Context: <no context> in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: The feature in question]

I recently started using Android Studio to work on my Android projects. I notice that at the bottom right corner of the IDE, there is the text `Context: <no context>`. Curiosity has gotten the best of me, so now I am searching online for more information. I have not found anything that resembles this functionality, so now I have come for you all.

What is this text for? What is it trying to display? How is it changed? How does it interact with my project?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you please explain how the approved answer sorted out you question, specifically referring to "What is this text for? What is it trying to display? How is it changed? How does it interact with my project?". Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contexts are like a visual bookmark of a set of files open and commonly used together.

You can load/save contexts from the Tools menu.  They come in handy when use in conjunction with Tasks that are linked to an Issue Tracker so all files you are editing for a particular issue are automatically opened when you switch to that task.

For full details of how to use them see the [IntellJ Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-tasks-and-context.html)

Comment: Could you please give an example of a case when the label "Context: <no context>" will be changed to something else?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand that, this has nothing to do with Contexts from the Tools-menu, but with NDK-Contexts.

First, creating a new context from the Tools-menu does not change "Context: " in the statusbar, second googling "Context " brought me to this bugtracker-entry:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187899

ie. previously there was a drop-down-menu in the statusbar, even when NDK was not installed. Now it says "not available", because NDK is not installed (?)
(But I didn't check, if that changes, when NDK is installed...)